# 404 Not found error when I type sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt

In a terminal when I insert this command line

`sudo apt-get update`

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct and the reason is: *No packages for Trusty in this PPA*. Remove the PPA. Open a terminal and run:

```
find /etc/apt -type f -name '*.list' -exec sudo sed -i '/gwibber-daily/d' {} \;
sudo apt-get update
```

The package `gwibber` is in the Trusty Universe repositories. To enable the repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the 'Software & Updates' program, click 'Other Software' - scroll down the list until you see an entry that looks something like `http://ppa.launchpad.net/ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa` and uncheck it's seleciton box.  This PPA does not support Ubuntu Trusty.